# C# RFC2898DeriveBytes is working but Python PBKDF2 generated key and IV are not working with Python AES Decryption

Tags: c#, python, pycrypto, pbkdf2, python-cryptography

I have a problem in hand to decrypt the AES encrypted cipher-text which specifications are following
The cipher-text consists of:
· 256 bytes of RFC2898-derived salt, followed by a message that was AES-encrypted using password, 'password' and derived IV.
Sample Message is "This is my secret string, lorem ipsum" and password is "password" which is encrypted using C# code
This message is decrypting fine with following c# code

```
private static readonly int SALT_SIZE = 256;
public static void Decrytor(){
// Encrypted Message
           var cipherText = "i+EKwmlAF0VYh4GwDd+bGf3+yreYsPJW2Oq/w9FXjsp7RI3VqRiqtnqiAD4n6U0JJSTe2ct4B7lgrG+dHxeGcXYEYIERXvU0xnUdH+z3mRwmgYOqCU9HRUKy/z3GKISTm8qH030KTYm3YMBjnKpU8gaRcoDPP/nCiB3o5fPdyspgJgT/qt5BuvwYq7n0qg6ez/Wi4447gq/qHwG3wuuYLSBUCfmIkgGaO1KXqv3SsR8EAhrmMBmPDJfjc3sydNqs5B8J9/JvZFEZULTb8rLQZKQvgHhH9/53Bzs3zmoq0RFbgSueUbyeWb9rLAzYieTz8Yj0srG4GtwPrTPoItc6/hvx5stZ6pX8tgyk9Y3baT0JFMtGgxve7yduy8idTCQdAwRc5NOo4+CBk7P/sIw6+Q==";
            var key = "password";
            // Extract the salt from our cipherText
            var allTheBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            var saltBytes = allTheBytes.Take(SALT_SIZE).ToArray();
            var cipherTextBytes = allTheBytes.Skip(SALT_SIZE).Take(allTheBytes.Length - SALT_SIZE).ToArray();

            var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltBytes);
            // Derive the previous IV from the Key and Salt
            var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
            var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            // The default Cipher Mode is CBC and the Padding is PKCS7 which are both good
            var aesManaged = new AesManaged();
            var decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
            var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);

            // Return the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream.
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\n", streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Output is: **"This is my secret string, lorem ipsum"**

but when I try to decrypt the message by following Python2.7 equivalent implementation, it is not decrypting the first few characters correctly

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol import KDF

def p_decrypt( self, text ):
    text_dec = base64.b64decode(text)
    salt = text_dec[:256]
    enc_txt = text_dec[256:]
    key_bytes = KDF.PBKDF2(self.key, salt, dkLen=32)
    iv = KDF.PBKDF2(self.key, salt)
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return cipher.decrypt(enc_txt)
```

**Output is: "�增��"j�����"t string, lorem ipsum"**

**Expected output: "This is my secret string, lorem ipsum"**

I tried to find the problem, when I used the keyBytes and IV generated by the C# RFC2898DeriveBytes method that also works fine python code but python code is not decrypting the whole message correctly using the PBKDF2 
generated keyBytes and IV.

*Both C# RFC2898DeriveBytes and python PBKDF2 are generating keyBytes using HMACSHA1 hashing algo but C# RFC2898DeriveBytes method is generated different keyBytes and IV whereas Python PBKDF2 is returning first 16 bytes of generated keyBytes for IV call*.

Kindly give me some helpful guidelines on this.

Thanks,
M Umer

Comment: This is **not** the proper way to generate an Initialization Vector. **IVs must be unique and need not be secret.** What you should do is generate the IV with a CPRNG (see RNGCryptoServiceProvider) and prepend it to the encrypted message.

Comment: (Obviously, the above does not really matter **if** the encryption key is used only once.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is a streaming-response object, so concatenating two successive calls is the same as doing one call with both lengths added together.

```
var pbkdf2WithTwoCalls = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(...)
var pbkdf2WithOneCall = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sameParametersAsAbove);

byte[] twoCallA = pbkdf2WithTwoCalls.GetBytes(32);
byte[] twoCallB = pbkdf2WithTwoCalls.GetBytes(16);

byte[] oneCall = pbkdf2WithOneCall.GetBytes(32 + 16);

if (!oneCall.SequenceEquals(twoCallA.Concat(twoCallB))
    throw new TheUniverseMakesNoSenseException();
```

So your solution in Python would be to make one 48-byte call to PBKDF2, then split it into the 32-byte AES key and the 16-byte IV.

Your decryption response indicates that the key is correct, but the IV is not.

Comment: Right, the Python code above use the first 16 bytes of the key as the IV. **If this was used to encrypt, this would leak half of the key in the process!**

Now, this points to another issue in this code: it basically makes the IV useless, because the IV depends solely on the password, just like the key. **IVs are meant to be nonces.** This means they should be used only once. Also, they are not meant to be kept secret and so are usually part of the message.

Comment: @ErwanLegrand  Encryption does not use the first 16 bytes of key as IV, "If this was used to encrypt, this would leak half of the key in the process!"

Comment: @bartonjs, It works, you really saved my time, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
# coding:utf8
# python3
# pip3 install pycryptodome

import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol import KDF
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad

cipherText = 'i+EKwmlAF0VYh4GwDd+bGf3+yreYsPJW2Oq/w9FXjsp7RI3VqRiqtnqiAD4n6U0JJSTe2ct4B7lgrG+dHxeGcXYEYIERXvU0xnUdH+z3mRwmgYOqCU9HRUKy/z3GKISTm8qH030KTYm3YMBjnKpU8gaRcoDPP/nCiB3o5fPdyspgJgT/qt5BuvwYq7n0qg6ez/Wi4447gq/qHwG3wuuYLSBUCfmIkgGaO1KXqv3SsR8EAhrmMBmPDJfjc3sydNqs5B8J9/JvZFEZULTb8rLQZKQvgHhH9/53Bzs3zmoq0RFbgSueUbyeWb9rLAzYieTz8Yj0srG4GtwPrTPoItc6/hvx5stZ6pX8tgyk9Y3baT0JFMtGgxve7yduy8idTCQdAwRc5NOo4+CBk7P/sIw6+Q=='
the_pass = 'password'

text_dec = base64.b64decode(cipherText)
salt = text_dec[:256]
enc_txt = text_dec[256:]
key_iv_bytes = KDF.PBKDF2(the_pass, salt, dkLen=48)

key = key_iv_bytes[:32]
iv = key_iv_bytes[32:]
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt(enc_txt)
plaintext = unpad(plaintext, 16)

print(plaintext)
# b'This is my secret string, lorem ipsum'
```